# Heroku free tier for a non-stop web and worker process in one application

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment

I have a Python app that pings an API every minute and records data into a database. I also have a Django web app that is the client for displaying this data (it should also not be idling, as I will explain bellow).

Heroku recently made changes again to their free tier, allowing 1000hrs/month for verified accounts. I have verified my account to take advantage of this. What is not clear to me is how the usage hours will be counted in my situation. Will my Heroku application accumulate ~750 hours per month, or 2x750 hours after non-stop running? Are the two lines inside the Procfile considered separate dynos, thus each will be accumulating 750 hours per month?

**Setup**

```html
Procfile:
worker: python api_crawler.py
web: gunicorn api_data_client.wsgi --log-file -
```

I found out that if the web process begins to idle after 30 minutes of inactivity, it will also bring down the worker process with it. This is not a desired outcome for me, as I need the worker process to be running non-stop. After some reading I found that the 'New Relic' monitoring addon can help keep the web process from idling, which is good, unless I will run out of the 1000 monthly hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in the procfile will create a separate dyno, so if you can't let either process idle, 1000 hours is not enough.
However, if you are ok with your web dyno idling after 30 minutes of inactivity, and presuming you don't have too much web traffic, you should be able to keep your worker process up 24/7, and your web process might consume less than approx. 250 dyno hours per month, so you could fit everything into the 1000 hour free tier.

Heroku should not be idling your worker process when your web process idles. Not sure why you wrote that you think it does.

Comment: Might be new policy, however it did indeed sleep my worker dyno when the web went to sleep, and I lost a couple of hours of data before I noticed this. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping -- "If an app has a web dyno, and that web dyno receives no traffic in a 30 minute period, the web dyno will sleep. In addition to the web dyno sleeping, the worker dyno (if present) will also sleep."

I ended up doing what you mentioned, but putting the web part in a separate app, so it can idle when needed, and not interrupting my worker.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I hadn't noticed the bit about web dyno idling causing the worker dyno to idle. But your solution of putting them in separate apps sounds like a good workaround. Just note that the limit of 1000 free dyno hours is per your entire account, so both your apps consume the free dyno hours from the same pool (assuming you have them both under the same account).

Comment: @StefanGloutnikov the link now (2019) says `Worker dynos do not sleep`, but it looks like a worker does not really eats 750 hours per month (at least if not used actively). My friend created a project with `web` + `worker` (Lumen queue) 2 months ago and he says that it used only 54 hours so far this month (23 days).